# Stop modal from playing all content on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are a couple of questions that deal with stopping iframe or video when Bootstrap modal is closed. But what if you can't predict what a user would add to the modal?

Is there a way to stop all content from playing when Bootstrap modal is closed? Is it possible inside

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: clean the dinamic content each time the modal is closed assuming you load content each time you open modal.